# Why use of static member is undefined in linux signal event

Tags: c++, linux, static

my Class look like follows:

```
AppStart{
static void SignalHandler(int signal){
    std::cout<< log_file_;
}
static void Start(){
//Set log_file_ path 
//Register signal handler 
}
static string log_file_;
}
```

When first time SignalHandler is getting called by sending signal using `kill` command it is printing the correct value. But when it is getting called multiple times is it giving undefined behavior. 
Why static variable is getting destroyed before finishing the execution of the program ?

Comment: How do you know it's undefined behaviour?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
Next time it is printing garbage value.

Comment: That doesn't mean in and of itself that there are no defined semantics here. Though it _is_ a fair indicator. (Note that for the purposes of this comment thread I've abstracted away the fact that you _are_ definitely invoking UB with your stream usage.)

Comment: May be there is some definition for this. But current as I am not aware of that the garbage value getting printed is undefined for me. So I used UB in my question. I will see if I can change that word with another proper word.

Comment: Not to mention that `AppStart::SignalHandler` uses a C++ ABI while the signal function is expecting a function that uses the C ABI. You may be getting lucky that they are the same on your platform. But is all it is luck, the code is non portable.

Comment: @LokiAstari But why same case don't apply if I change log_file to  global variable in same C++ file?

Comment: @VivekGoel: In this case, the scope in which `log_file` is declared should be inconsequential.  The handler is invoking undefined behavior, and trying to characterize undefined behavior is a futile exercise.

Answer (score 5):

Invoking `operator<<()` on `std::cout` is not an [asychronous signal-safe function](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers) ... therefore you should not be using it inside a signal handler.  Any use thereof will invoke undefined or at best indeterminate behavior.  You can see a list of possibile alternative candidates for output, such as the low-level `write()`, etc. in the link I've provided.

Comment: but will log_file_ having proper memory when second time signal is getting called or will it be undefined?

Comment: @VivekGoel: About the only thing you can do in a signal handler is set a flag that is then checked inside the main code. Doing nearly anything else in a signal handler is asking for trouble.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks. But I have one question,  currently if log_file_ memory location is not valid, if signal handler is getting nth time. How can I be sure that any other flag variable memory location will remain valid?

Comment: @VivekGoel: `log_file_` is a complex object that is manipulated by a set of function calls. Your problem is that if the functions do not complete then the object is an invalid state. Have you determined that another signal is not interrupting your signal handler in the middle of its operation!

Comment: @LokiAstari how to check that ?